# Estimating the location of largest entry

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equations of the form

\begin{align}
\mathbf{y=Ax+n},
\end{align}

which is possibly under-determined, and I am interested in estimating the location of the largest entry of $\mathbf{x}$. Now if $\mathbf{x}$ was sparse, I can see how this was possible, however, in my case $\mathbf{x}$ is not necessarily sparse. Is there any literature that addresses problem of this sort?

Many thanks for your help!

Best,

Comment: What do u mean by x not being necessarily sparse?

Comment: What do you mean by location of the largest entry of $x$, assuming that there are infinitely many solutions?